# How to make a loop to try all sorting possibilities of x items in Python

Tags: python, list, loops

This is what I mean by sorting (5 items in this example, this is not code):

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
[1, 2, 4, 3, 5]
etc.
```

It is some kind of factorial function. Without items repeating.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `itertools`:

```
import itertools
print [i for i in itertools.permutations([1,2,3,4,5])]
```